# Адаптивный дизайн с уменьшенной версией

Tags: html, css, css3, media-queries

Делаю адаптивный дизайн, есть вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы не пришлось адаптировать сайт для каждого разрешения экрана, но сделать так, чтобы при вхождении на сайт, пользователи получали полную версию сайта, но в уменьшенном виде, не знаю, как называется точно.
Возможно замечали, у сайтов, где нет мобильной версии открывается полная версия, и она уменьшена, чтобы прочитать что либо, приходится приближать этот текст, это я и имею ввиду.

Comment: То что вы описываете "получали полную версию сайта, но в уменьшенном виде" делаете не вы и не сайт, а браузер установлен на мобильном устройстве...

Comment: Смотрите в сторону `<meta name="viewport" />`

Comment: все , проблему решил, адаптировал через @media queries

Answer (score 0):

Примените размеры как %, а не как статичные. Примените **viewport** и поиграйте с его разрешением - [**инфо Гугл**](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/set-the-viewport) + **[инфо W3](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)**